# Login не отправляет письмо активации на на почту MODX

Tags: modx, smtp, email, login

Пилю личный кабинет на боевом сервере с помощью login. Использую способ регистрации при котором отправляется активационная ссылка на указанную почту. На локальном сервере все работало, письма формировались в текстовых файлах.
Пробовал разворачиваться на двух разных хостах, нигде не работает. Пробовал настраивать smtp - не работает. Что нужно сделать, чтобы login начал отправлять письма? Второй день ковыряюсь... Версия 2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Если укого-нибудь возникнет такая трабла, то вот что делать. Протестируйте отправку сообщений с помощью плагина QuickMail, вызовите на странице [[!QuickEmail? &debug=`1`]] и посмотрите, что вернет. Если отправка не удалась, то возможно отправка запрещена конфигурацией сервера. Тогда нужно включать функцию mail. Если все ок, но письма нет, то оно могло попасть в спам, но например gmail может даже до спама не допустить. Поэтому лучше проверить на какой-нибудь слабозащищенной почте. У меня письмо не доходило потому, что отправлялось с домена на котором не было сертификата.